# Snakemake: Data-dependent conditional execution of rules, IndexError

Tags: snakemake

When executing the below snakemake pipeline, I get an error: IndexError: list index out of range. I think it's because fastqc_pretrim is being executed for all SAMPLEs. However, not all samples pass basecalling QC, so only some files will need to be processed here. I am trying to use checkpointing to get this to run. Looking at the log, we can see it is trying to run fastqc_pretrim for sample "FAQ20773_pass_barcode01_68fda206_1".  However, if you look above that line in the LOG, FAQ20773_fail_barcode03_68fda206_0 is actually the only sample that passed with a .fastq.gz file.  I'm not sure why the correct sample is not running.

LOG:

```
snakemake --use-conda --jobs 1 -pr
['FAQ20773_fail_barcode01_68fda206_0', 'FAQ20773_pass_barcode01_68fda206_2', 'FAQ20773_fail_barcode03_68fda206_0', 'FAQ20773_fail_barcode02_68fda206_0', 'FAQ20773_pass_barcode01_68fda206_0', 'FAQ20773_pass_barcode01_68fda206_1']
The flag 'directory' used in rule guppy_basecall_persample is only valid for outputs, not inputs.        
Building DAG of jobs...                                                                                                                                                                                  
Updating job fastqc_pretrim.                                                                                                                                                                           
basecall/FAQ20773_fail_barcode01_68fda206_0                                                                                                                                                               
[]                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Updating job all.                                                                                                                                                                                         
Updating job fastqc_pretrim.                                                                                                                                                                              
basecall/FAQ20773_pass_barcode01_68fda206_2                                                                                                                                                               
[]                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Updating job all.                                                                                                                                                                                         
Updating job fastqc_pretrim.                                                                                                                                                                              
basecall/FAQ20773_fail_barcode03_68fda206_0                                                                                                                                                               
['basecall/FAQ20773_fail_barcode03_68fda206_0/pass/fastq_runid_68fda20603fe08e9e2a4eef8718997203b603497_0_0.fastq.gz']                                                                                    
Updating job all.                                                                                                                                                                                         
Updating job fastqc_pretrim.                                                                                                                                                                              
basecall/FAQ20773_fail_barcode02_68fda206_0                                                                                                                                                               
[]                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Updating job all.                                                                                                                                                                                         
Updating job fastqc_pretrim.                                                                                                                                                                              
basecall/FAQ20773_pass_barcode01_68fda206_0                                                                                                                                                               
[]                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Updating job all.                                                                                                                                                                                         
Updating job fastqc_pretrim.                                                                                                                                                                              
basecall/FAQ20773_pass_barcode01_68fda206_1                                                                                                                                                               
[]                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Updating job all.                                                                                                                                                                                         
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash                   

[Thu Aug 26 13:13:51 2021]                                                                                                                                                                                
rule fastqc_pretrim:                                                                                                                                                                                          
output: qc/fastqc_pretrim/FAQ20773_pass_barcode01_68fda206_1.html, qc/fastqc_pretrim/FAQ20773_pass_barcode01_68fda206_1_fastqc.zip                                                                        
log: logs/fastqc_pretrim/FAQ20773_pass_barcode01_68fda206_1.log                                                                                                                                           
jobid: 19                                                                                                                                                                                                 
reason: Missing output files: qc/fastqc_pretrim/FAQ20773_pass_barcode01_68fda206_1_fastqc.zip                                                                                                             
wildcards: sample=FAQ20773_pass_barcode01_68fda206_1                                                                                                                                                      
resources: tmpdir=/tmp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
/home/hvasquezgross/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/bin/python3.9 /mypool/projects/steve_frese/snakemake_guppy_basecall/.snakemake/scripts/tmpzxqxx28h.wrapper.py                                               
Activating conda environment: /mypool/projects/steve_frese/snakemake_guppy_basecall/.snakemake/conda/224336800b4f74953334e368c2f338c4                                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                          
File "/mypool/projects/steve_frese/snakemake_guppy_basecall/.snakemake/scripts/tmpzxqxx28h.wrapper.py", line 41, in <module>                                                                                shell(                                                                                                                                                                                                  File "/home/hvasquezgross/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/shell.py", line 130, in __new__                                                                                   cmd = format(cmd, *args, stepout=2, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                           File "/home/hvasquezgross/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/utils.py", line 427, in format                                                                                    return fmt.format(_pattern, *args, **variables)                                                                                                                                                         File "/home/hvasquezgross/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.9/string.py", line 161, in format                                                                                                           return self.vformat(format_string, args, kwargs)                                                                                                                                                        
File "/home/hvasquezgross/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.9/string.py", line 165, in vformat                                                                                                          result, _ = self._vformat(format_string, args, kwargs, used_args, 2)                                                                                                                                    
File "/home/hvasquezgross/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.9/string.py", line 205, in _vformat                                                                                                         obj, arg_used = self.get_field(field_name, args, kwargs)                                                                                                                                                
File "/home/hvasquezgross/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.9/string.py", line 278, in get_field                                                                                                        obj = obj[i]                                                                                                                                                                                            
File "/home/hvasquezgross/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/io.py", line 1536, in __getitem__                                                                                 return super().__getitem__(key)                                                                                                                                                                       
IndexError: list index out of range                                                                                                                                                                       
[Thu Aug 26 13:13:52 2021]                                                                                                                                                                                
Error in rule fastqc_pretrim:                                                                                                                                                                                 
jobid: 19                                                                                                                                                                                                 
output: qc/fastqc_pretrim/FAQ20773_pass_barcode01_68fda206_1.html, qc/fastqc_pretrim/FAQ20773_pass_barcode01_68fda206_1_fastqc.zip                                                                        
log: logs/fastqc_pretrim/FAQ20773_pass_barcode01_68fda206_1.log (check log file(s) for error message)                                                                                                     
conda-env: /mypool/projects/steve_frese/snakemake_guppy_basecall/.snakemake/conda/224336800b4f74953334e368c2f338c4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
RuleException:                                                                                                                                                                                            
CalledProcessError in line 60 of /mypool/projects/steve_frese/snakemake_guppy_basecall/Snakefile:                                                                                                         
Command 'source /home/hvasquezgross/miniconda3/bin/activate '/mypool/projects/steve_frese/snakemake_guppy_basecall/.snakemake/conda/224336800b4f74953334e368c2f338c4'; /home/hvasquezgross/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/bin/python3.9 /mypool/projects/steve_frese/snakemake_guppy_basecall/.snakemake/scripts/tmpzxqxx28h.wrapper.py' returned non-zero exit status 1.                                                  
File "/mypool/projects/steve_frese/snakemake_guppy_basecall/Snakefile", line 60, in __rule_fastqc_pretrim                                                                                                 
File "/home/hvasquezgross/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 52, in run                                                                                        
Shutting down, this might take some time.                                                                                                                                                                 
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

Snakemake

```
import glob                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
configfile: "config.yaml"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
inputdirectory=config["directory"]                                                                                                                                                                        
SAMPLES, = glob_wildcards(inputdirectory+"/{sample}.fast5", followlinks=True)                                                                                                                             
print(SAMPLES)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
wildcard_constraints:                                                                                                                                                                                         
sample="\w+\d+_\w+_\w+\d+_.+_\d"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
##### target rules #####                                                                                                                                                                                  
rule all:                                                                                                                                                                                                     
input:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   expand('basecall/{sample}/sequencing_summary.txt', sample=SAMPLES),                                                                                                                                       
   "qc/multiqc.html"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

rule make_indvidual_samplefiles:                                                                                                                                                                              
input:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   inputdirectory+"/{sample}.fast5",                                                                                                                                                                     
output:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   "lists/{sample}.txt",                                                                                                                                                                                 
shell:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   "basename {input}  > {output}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        


checkpoint guppy_basecall_persample:                                                                                                                                                                          
input:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   directory=directory(inputdirectory),                                                                                                                                                                      
   samplelist="lists/{sample}.txt",                                                                                                                                                                      
output:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   summary="basecall/{sample}/sequencing_summary.txt",                                                                                                                                                       
   directory=directory("basecall/{sample}/"),                                                                                                                                                            
params:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   config["basealgo"]                                                                                                                                                                                    
shell:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   "guppy_basecaller -i {input.directory} --input_file_list {input.samplelist} -s {output.directory} -c {params} --compress_fastq -x \"auto\" --gpu_runners_per_device 3 --num_callers 2 --chunks_per_runner 200"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        


def aggregate_input(wildcards):                                                                                                                                                                               
   checkpoint_output = checkpoints.guppy_basecall_persample.get(**wildcards).output[1]                                                                                                                       
   print(checkpoint_output)                                                                                                                                                                                  
   exparr = expand("basecall/{sample}/pass/{runid}.fastq.gz", sample=wildcards.sample, 
   runid=glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_output, "pass/", "{runid}.fastq.gz")).runid)                             
   print(exparr)                                                                                                                                                                                             
   return exparr    

rule fastqc_pretrim:
    input:
        aggregate_input
    output:
        html="qc/fastqc_pretrim/{sample}.html",
        zip="qc/fastqc_pretrim/{sample}_fastqc.zip" # the suffix _fastqc.zip is necessary for multiqc to find the file. If not using multiqc, you are free to choose an arbitrary filename
    params: ""
    log:
        "logs/fastqc_pretrim/{sample}.log"
    threads: 1
    wrapper:
        "0.77.0/bio/fastqc"

rule multiqc:
    input:
        #expand("basecall/{sample}.fastq.gz", sample=SAMPLES)
        expand("qc/fastqc_pretrim/{sample}_fastqc.zip", sample=SAMPLES)
    output:
        "qc/multiqc.html"
    params:
        ""  # Optional: extra parameters for multiqc.
    log:
        "logs/multiqc.log"
    wrapper:
        "0.77.0/bio/multiqc"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making things more complicated than necessary by using `checkpoint` and `wrapper`. This is what I would do, more or less:

```
rule guppy_basecall_persample:
    input:
        ...
    output:
        summary="basecall/{sample}/sequencing_summary.txt",                                                                                                                                                       
        directory=directory("basecall/{sample}/"),
    shell:
        r"""
        guppy ...
        """

rule fastqc_pretrim:
    input:
        directory= directory("basecall/{sample}/"),
    output:
        html="qc/fastqc_pretrim/{sample}.html",
        zip="qc/fastqc_pretrim/{sample}_fastqc.zip"
    shell:
        r"""
        fastqc {input.directory}/pass/*.fastq.gz
        """
```

Comment: I think the problem with this method is that not all samples will have passed the filtering stage. So not every sample file with end up having a pass folder, so I need to conditionally use the samples that passed.

I was hoping to use checkpointing to re-evaluate the SAMPLE names and only proceed with ones that passed.